# Using npm install from any location without making new package-lock.json everytime?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install, package-lock.json

I'm using visual studio code. I have multiple folders and package.json is in ProjectName/ProjectName.Web folder.

Do i have to enter this folder in terminal everytime i want to run npm install?

When I'm trying to do it from ProjectName folder which is deafult location in terminal in vs code it creates package-lock.json in this main directory. Is it possible to maybe change npm config so it knows where the package.json and package-lock.json is so it doesn't create new package-lock.json every timeand it works from other directories in project?

Answer (score 1):

`package-lock.json` will be created every time you run `npm install`. It's not recommended, but you can disable the `package-lock.json` generation, check here https://codeburst.io/disabling-package-lock-json-6be662f5b97d, i hope it helps you